# Changing multiple text styles at once

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pdflatex

So I have imported a csv file and made a data frame called stat (I have left this part of the code out for brevity). With this data frame that I am trying to make a PDF with each row having its own page. I want the first column of the data frame (stat[1] in the code below) to be the "title" of each page as it is the player's name. At the moment I can make the player's name bold or change its colour but I can't seem to work out how to do multiple changes to one variable all at once.

Ultimately I would like to increase the font size, centre the text and make it bold.

Everything I read talks about how to do this outside of a chunk or during a chunk but not during a function/do loop. I am relatively new to R so all of this is quite confusing.

```
---
output: pdf_document
---
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(ggrepel)
library(ggimage)
library(ggthemes)
```

```
fun <- function(stat){
  cat("\\textbf{", stat[1], "}\n") 
  cat("\n")
  cat("Club: ", stat[2], "\n")
  cat("\n")
  cat("Age: ", stat[3], "\n")
  cat("\n")
  cat("Position(s) (Category): ", stat[4], " (", stat[5], ") \n", sep="")
  cat("\n")
  cat("Minutes Played (Full Game Equivalent): ", stat[6], " (", stat[7], ") \n", sep="")
  cat("\n")
  cat("Goals (per 90): ", stat[8], " (", stat[9], ") \n", sep="")
  cat("\n")
  cat("Assists (per 90): ", stat[10], " (", stat[11], ") \n", sep="")
  cat("\n")
  print(kable(stat[12:28], col.names=NULL) %>% kable_styling(full_width = F, position = "left"))
  cat("\n\\newpage\n")
}
apply(stat, 1, fun)
```

So cat("\textbf{", stat[1], "}\n") returns the player's name in bold and I can also do cat("\textcolor{blue}{", stat[1], "}\n") to return the player's name in blue but if I true something like cat("\textcolor{blue}\textbf{", stat[1], "}\n") the code won't compile.

I don't necessarily want the text to be blue but I don't know how to change the font size or to centre the text at all in this way so I tried to make it both blue and bold and failed.

**Edit:** Another thought I had was to make the player's name an actual header and customise/edit what headers look like.

ie use cat("##", stat[1], "\n") and then somewhere else in the code define what this header looks like. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out. The final line of code is:

```
cat("\\begin{center}", "\\fontsize{20pt}{2pt}\\selectfont\\textbf{", stat[1], "}\n", "\\end{center}")
```

This site helped me a lot in case anyone else has similar problems to me:

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Text_alignment